# Activity onStart() not called when resuming an recreated activity from a stack

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

**Long story short:** I am currently working on a small android game. One feature is being able to change the app theme. When the user changes the theme, an event is broadcasted throughout the app and all active activities call recreate() to apply the new theme.

**The problem:**
Let's say there is a stack of activities: A, B, C. All activities will receive the event in the order they were opened and call recreate(). These are the lifecycle events that will get called (in order):

- Activity A will call onDestroy(), onCreate(), onStart(), onResume() and onPause()
- Activity B will call onDestroy(), onCreate(), onStart(), onResume() and onPause()
- Activity C will call onPause(), onStop(), onDestroy(), onCreate(), onStart(), onResume().

Note that neither activity A or B called onStop(). **When those activities are being returned to (eg. back button press), they will not call onStart() when they become visible**, but will call onResume(). This is contrary to what is stated in the activity lifecycle documentation.

**The question:** Is there something I'm doing wrong here? Is there another way to restart all activities in an application without messing up the activity lifecycle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are taking the wrong approach here. You should not use the framework calls in order to change your theme. The issue you are having is that you are not calling `onStop` as the framework would, but even so...

The primary reason your approach is incorrect is that Android may have already destroyed an `Activity` if it is not visible. So sending events to it that call framework methods is not only unnecessary at that point, but it could result in unpredictable states and behavior. Could even cause a crash.

For changes to your theme or any UI component, you should handle that in `onResume` - in other words handle changes to the UI elements when the user returns to the `Activity`. One option for doing this is passing flags through `startActivityForResult`.

Better, make your theme selection persist using `sharedPreferences` (or using another method) and then read from that when the `Activity` is resumed. This would ensure the proper theme is selected regardless of how the user gets to the `Activity`.

EDIT:

Note that the `Activity` framework methods are `public` not because they should be accessed at any time or by other classes, but because that is required for them to be implemented in your app. They are not intended to be invoked outside the framework.

You should note that in the official documentation for `Activity` none of the methods you are calling are listed as "Public Methods" (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#Activity()). You are using them in an unsupported way. However, I only point this out to make you aware of it and that it is not a generally accepted approach to solving this problem.

Comment: The recreate event (I'm using EventBus here) is only registered between onCreate() and onDestroy()  for each activity so no issue there. Taking the startActivityForResult() / onResume() way will result in an ugly flicker for each resumed activity if the theme changes, and I'm trying to avoid that. Also, the activity's recreate() method I am using is a public call added in API 11.

Comment: I edited my response - even using EventBus for this approach is something I would avoid. And have you tested the "ugly flicker"? I'm assuming "yes" - if so, you should consider animations or another approach that handles this. Maybe post that question here? Because you should not call "onStart" or "onResume" while the Activity is not visible - that could be part of the problem, but it's only a guess.

Comment: I think you got the question a bit wrong. I never said I am calling these lifecycle methods. I said these methods are called by the os, and I enumerated the order, pointing out that onStop() does not get called even if the activity is not visible. I am only using the public method recreate() to trigger the activity recreation. This method is documented here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#recreate%28%29

Comment: You are correct that I didn't understand exactly what you were doing. However, the point I am trying to address is still valid. Calling `reCreate` is not the appropriate approach. You are forcing lifecycle calls that are not appropriate to call when the `Activity` is not visible. Although you have a very creative approach, I don't think that is the intended use of that method. I am trying to answer your question, "Is there something wrong that I'm doing here?" - Yes. For example, you are forcing a call to "onCreate" for an Activity that is in the background. You should not do that.

Comment: Yes, calling recreate() on a paused, stopped activity leads to unexpected behaviour. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly in line with the documentation.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html

If you look at the chart, onResume gets called when returning to an activity no matter what but onStart doesn't.

Comment: Yes, but the same documentation states that if an activity is hidden completely, then the onStop() will get called - and in this case it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change UI related component then you must use OnResume method instead of recreating all activities. like following.

```
    @override
    onResume()
    {
    textview.setText("Change text When activity resumes");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Colleagues above responded very well.
The behavior you reported. The onstart and onResume not be called. I've watched it happening to Hot Code Swapping. It is worth stopping the application and call the rebuild.